# Remove 'and' from numname strings of ordinals

Tags: number

Is there a way using the `numname` package, to have the ordinal written out for long English numbers not include the word 'and'?  That is, I would like \OrdinalToName{118} to produce 'One Hundred Eighteen' instead of the current 'One Hundred **and** Eighteen'.

Answer (score 2):

The expected output of `\OrdinalToName{118}` would actually be 'One Hundred Eighteenth'. If you want this cardinal number instead of the ordinal number, use `\NumToName` instead.

That out of the way, let's focus in the unwanted conjunction:

Taking a look at the `numname` package manual, we find the hint

> This code was cut and paste from the `memoir.cls` for use as an independent package [...]

Looking through the `memoir` manual, we can find the following: (See section 18.14.2 Named numbers, currently starting on page 337)

> By default some punctuation and conjunctions are used in the representation of named numbers. [...] These macros are initially defined as:

```
\newcommand*{\namenumberand}{ and }
\newcommand*{\namenumbercomma}{, }
\newcommand*{\tensunitsep}{-}
```

In order to overwrite this default to get rid of the 'and' conjunction, just add `\renewcommand*{\namenumberand}{ }` to your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numname}
\begin{document}
\NumToName{118}

\OrdinalToName{118}

\renewcommand*{\namenumberand}{ }
\NumToName{118} 

\OrdinalToName{118}
\end{document}
```

[image]